# delete trigger not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a delete trigger on a table in my DB that is supposed to be inserting rows into an "audit" table, but when I delete rows from the trigger table, they do not show up in the audit table. I have insert and update triggers following this same format that work fine but I can't seem to get this one to work. Here is the trigger:

```
USE [OutageDev]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_audOutageSummaryDelete]
ON [dbo].[Outage Summary]
AFTER DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO dbo.[Outage Summary Audit]
                  (OutageSummaryID,
                   Dispatcher,
                   /*Removed columns for brevity*/
                   StateEmergency,
                   Comment,
                   AuditDateTime,
                   AuditUser,
                   AuditAction)
      SELECT d.OutageSummaryID,
             d.Dispatcher,
             /*Removed columns for brevity*/
             d.StateEmergency,
             t.Comment,
             GETDATE(),
             SUSER_SNAME(),
             'DELETE'
      FROM   deleted d
             JOIN [Outage Summary] t
               ON d.OutageSummaryID = t.OutageSummaryID
  END
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Do rows definitely match the `OutageSummaryID` in the deleted records? If so is the trigger definitely enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The trigger is enabled. OutageSummaryID is the PK for the table so I assumed they would have to match.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realize the join was back onto the base table. You shouldn't have the `JOIN` at all. Just use `d.Comment` instead of `t.Comment` and get rid of the join.

Comment: Well there is another issue that I should also address and might be causing the issue here. The Comment column is of type ntext so for my update and insert triggers I select it from the trigger table. But, now that I think about it, that probably can't work on an after delete trigger because the row would already be deleted, ya?

Comment: Yes that won't work. As you are on 2008 can't you change the column datatype to `nvarchar(max)` which doesn't have this limitation?

Comment: Yes! Works perfectly. If you would like to put that as answer I would gladly accept it for you. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I was joining the deleted table with the trigger table in order to select columns that were of type ntext because this was how it worked for my insert and update triggers. Since this is an after delete trigger, the row I was trying to select was already deleted. I converted columns from ntext to nvarchar(max) and got rid of the join and it works fine now.